# Where can i find androidmk tool to convert Android.mk to Android.bp?

Tags: android, android-ndk

Currently, i am trying to convert Android.mk to Android.bp. I am doing it manually. But when i read about [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/soong/) blog

I found using **androidmk** tool, we can convert easily Android.mk to Android.bp.

But, i am not able to find anywhere.

Please suggest me some solution.

Comment: Is this actually an NDK question? Android.bp is not for the NDK, it's for building AOSP itself.

Comment: Yes I am working on AOSP,  Can you please tell me , how to do the Coversions??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to only run below command:-

`source build/envsetup.sh`

`cd "the directory where android.mk to be converted is present"`

`androidmk Android.mk`

Then Copy the output to Android.bp file

Comment: how to convert android.bp to android.mk?

Comment: It would be simple enough to write one that handles your case. Please refer Android.mk file standards and plenty of examples available. Search for any Package in AOSP codebase.

Comment: @teoten In ideal situation, One would be interested to convert Makefile to Blueprint not the other way around.

Answer (score 12):

Clone the full android source and prepare for a build like usual, using `. build/envsetup.sh`, then run `make blueprint_tools`. Now you can simply run `androidmk` and the command will be in your PATH.

Comment: After this I could use androidmk. However, I my regular Android build started failing as [100% 1/1] out/soong/.minibootstrap/minibp out/soong/.bootstrap/build.ninja
FAILED: out/soong/.bootstrap/build.ninja
out/soong/.minibootstrap/minibp -t -l out/.module_paths/Android.bp.list -b out/soong -n out -d out/soong/.bootstrap/build.ninja.d -globFile out/soong/.minibootstrap/build-globs.ninja -o out/soong/.bootstrap/build.ninja Android.bp
error removing abandoned files: log entry has too few fields: "379188\t380202\t1607423502\tout/target/product/mysore".  So I had to rm out/.ninja_log

Comment: Thanks Hack5 and Lavakush. Keep helping.